# "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" When Opening Folders in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, directory, permission-denied, errno

I'm trying to read/open a folder in Windows 10 using python. Unfortunately, when I attempt to read a file using this command:

```
open(r'D:\Documents')
```

I'm always met with this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\Documents'
```

This error doesn't occur when I read a file:

```
open(r'D:\Documents\test.txt')
```

What's odd is that I've right-clicked on the folder, selected **Proprieties**, when to the **Security** tab, I gave full permission to all users, and I'm still receiving this error. I'm executing this command in the Python IDE after selecting **Run As Administrator** on the shortcut. Am I missing a step here?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by opening folder?

Comment: I started writing a script to copy folders from one directory to another. That is where I first encountered [Errno 13]. I tested whether it was an issue with my script or an issue with folder permissions. It appears it's a permissions error. I don't know why windows is refusing to let me read or change the folders via python. If I can figure out how to read the folder using the python shell, then I can figure out from there how to make my script work.

Comment: You can just use [`shutil.copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I've tried that beforehand, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Looks like ```shutil.copytree()``` only works on files, not directories. I'll have to rework my code to fix this. I'll create new folders for the directories I want to copy.

Comment: `copytree(src, dst, dirs_exist_ok=True)` works perfectly with folders on my system.